# Android 12 Scoped Storage Migration: Exchange Data from public sdcard-directory to App-internal-directory and vice versa

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I'll have an **Android App** currently compiled against the API29 which I'm working on an **update for API31.**
The App is using an huge ultralite database which is located in the directory
**/sdcard/Documents/myApp/db**

Because I now have to apply scoped storage', I'll use the App-Directory on the external sdcard by using **context.getExternalFilesDir(null)**.
I'll have to fulfill an important requirement, that the User needs to download this big database by PC only once
and store this db- file in a dedicated directory on the Android Device.
This will be done from a person (in a staging role) that prepares dozens of devices for dozens of users in a staging process,
so not alle devices needs to download the DB for themselfes.

**When the App is starting it will have a look on this staging-directory and would then move the DB-file to the internal Working storage of the APP.**

**So my question is:**
How can I get the permission for myApp to **grant myApp access to a dedicated directory** on the SDCard e.g. **/sdcard/Documents/myApp/db** in a way
that the user can provide there a db for myAPP, **which myApp will move to internal storage** in case of no DB, is present?
It would be also important to just set this permissions once on a device and having then the app confirmed to have access to this directory as long as installed on the device.
(**/sdcard/Documents/myApp/db  -> app-internal-dir**)

**Constraints:**
It's no option to use via API29 in the AndroidManifest android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". Reason:
I anyway need to provide up a mechanism, where the user can copy a db file to the SD-Card which the app will use in case of no DB is present.
The app should then move (not copy) this huge file into its app directory.
I would also like to have a dedicated directory on the sdcard, where the application can move the current DB into it. (Do the opposite: **app-internal-dir -> /sdcard/Documents/myApp/db-export**)
It is no option to use the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, due this app is not a classified App that would get the permission from Google to do that (like a filebrowser or a antivirus App)

**Can anybody give me some recommendation which approach to use?**

The whole Logic is currently used by File Objects and Paths to working directories with the java.io.File-API

Thanks in advance!

EDITED:
I'm able to open the folder and query the DocumentFiles when it returns from the picker:

Here is my code that starts the picker:

```
// Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
                    // the system file picker when it loads.
                    val pathAfterPrimaryIndicator = bootstrapViewModel.getDbMigrationDirectoryName()?.substringAfter("/0/")
                    val uri =DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri("com.android.externalstorage.documents", "primary:$pathAfterPrimaryIndicator")
                    putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri)
                }
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, DOCUMENT_TREE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST)
```

Here is some code that handles the return:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == DOCUMENT_TREE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {
        val treeUri: Uri? = data!!.data
        val pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri!!)
        pickedDir?.listFiles()?.forEach {
            // test if its a Db file and move it to the internal storage
            if (it.isFile) {
              // QUESTION: -->  How can I MOVE  those files (some files are huge) found here to the app-internal directory?
            }

        }
```

The question is now still open how to MOVE the directory content into the app internal directory. Because some of the files are huge so copy them is not really an Option. How can this be done?

Comment: `It's no option to use via API29 in the AndroidManifest android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". ` You should use that option and leave it it manifest. It is needed for Android 10 devices. It does not harm other devices.

Comment: `/sdcard/Documents/myApp/db-export` Your app can download and place the file there.  The app can do that without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: `Because I now have to apply scoped storage'` Wel.... Are you shure? Your app can still use the db on /sdcard/Documents/myApp/db. Well if it created the db itself there.

Comment: You should not talk about /sdcard/Documents but /storage/emulated/0/Documents and yet better: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`. All yopu want  has nothing to do with a removable micro-sd card so namings with sdcard are confusing.

Comment: @blackapps
Thanks for the infos.
Afaik when I compile against API 31 the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will be ignored.
permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` isn't an option (see constraints in post). As you said myApp can Access the db in /sdcard/Documents/myApp/db if it was created by myApp. But if the user dowloads it by an Filebrowser or by an uninstalled Version of myApp it can't be accessed directly anymore by myApp.

Comment: You did not understand my comments. Repeat: leave requestLegacyExternalStorage in manifest. You do not need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I said that before.

Comment: What you tell about downloading not by your app comes true. You then need ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. But let the app download itself and you have full access.

Comment: @blackapps: Indeed I did missunderstood your comment regarding 'MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'. Sorry about that!!!

Yes I'm aware if the current running instance of myApp is the file-creater its not requiring permissions in documents folder to access. But either an earlier uninstalled instance of myApp or the user can have placed the db there. 
Then listing the directory content from myApp finds  0 elements (even if a db is in directory). Then something additionally will be needed

Comment: Download the db would be technical possible, but in my case makes no sense, because:
the db already could be available in /sdcard/Documents/myApp/db and I would not like to enforce a redownload of the db (several GBs) just for having access. The not accessible db should be removed in any case, so I will need some construct giving me access to operate on the db.

Comment: `Then something additionally will be needed` My god.. use ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select the file. Further you did not explain why you started talking about a FileExplorer.

Comment: @blackapps:
I appreciate very much that you are spending your time for helping me, but please don't be upset, if I'm not that experienced like you are. I thought there will be something additionally needed, because I would like to move this huge file (not open and copy) from /sdcard/Documents/myApp/db to app-internal-dir. I do not find the possibility to move the file with this approach. I hoped something would be possible to gain the permission to a parent directory and move its whole content to the app internal directory.

Comment: You have that possibility. It has been told to you already how to do it. Better post your code.

Comment: @blackapps: I followed your recommendation and updated the post with some code snippets. I placed in the comment "// QUESTION: --->" 
I did not found any information up to now, how to achieve a MOVE of all the files in the picked directory  using this approach.

Comment: You first make a copy. Then delete the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Android 11+:

If the file comes from a PC then the officer can directly place the file in getExternalFilesDir(null) and you are done.

If the officer places the file in a public directory of external storage then your app should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user choose the file.

Comment: Hi blackapps. Thanks for this proposal!
At first I thought exactly the same! The location of  context.getExternalFilesDir(null) is then in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mydomain.myApp 
But then I saw that e.g. the Standard-File-Browser of a Samsung S10 lite(Android 11) is not able to show any content from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data. 
On my pixel (Android12) device I'm running Solid-Explorer a payed File-Browser, therewith it can be done. But it should be doable with standard-file-browsers from android-devices. And there are some conditions, where this dir is not accessible.

Comment: I have no idea why you started talking about the standard file explorer. It does not come into play for the things i said and the things you wanted in your original post. Not that it is not true what you said but to me its irrelevant for what you want.

Comment: I did mention the standard file explorer, so the user could simply copy db to the destination directory without adb or additional file browsers. 
I like your proposal,
but unfortunately this approach is not working. If the File is copied outside of myApp (via adb or file browser) even to the location that 'context.getExternalDir(null)' is returning, then myApp only has read- but no write-permission to it. But it is crucial to have write access to this db.
Prob. would need to ask user for permission, even if it is in the appExternalFileDir. Very sad that google does not supporting this!

Comment: Your app can write to that file once the user choosed it.